# Groovy Support in STS 3.9.0

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am wondering is there no Groovy Support more in STS. I just wanted to give Groovy and Gradle a try with a new mini project and I remember in the past time there were a GGTS (Groovy&Grails Tool Suite).

Somehow I am not finding any Groovy IDE what works in STS 3.9.0 (Neon). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pivotal has [dropped](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/groovy-2-4-and-grails-3-0-to-be-last-major-releases-under-pivotal-sponsorship) support for groovy in 2015 and with that the development of GGTS and the groovy plugin.

Fortunately the [groovy-eclipse plugin](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki) is in development again, but there was no release for quite a while. The snapshot builds are stable enough in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but if you want an IDE that supports Groovy and Gradle really well, then [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) is now my go-to choice. And, yes, the free community edition provides full Groovy support.

Comment: Thank you Neil, I need to give IntelliJ a try one time :-)